# AspnetCore RazorPage return raw string?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

RazorPage typically return void, Task, IActionResult, such as

```
public Task OnGet() { }
public Task<IActionResult> OnGet() { }
```

It's also possible having a handler returning Json, like

```
public Task<JsonResult> OnGetAlso() { }
```

But there are scenarios where I want the handler to return raw string, but I couldn't find an easy way to do this.

```
public Task<string> OnGetSomeString() 
{ return "something"; }
```

But I always get errors Unsupported handler method return type.  Is this possible?  Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a `ContentResult` to return `string` content:

```
public IActionResult OnGetSomeString()
{
    return Content("something");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, and be sure to check out all the other [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.content?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for the `Content` method as well as all the properties/methods of the entire [PageModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `TextOutputFormatter`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new TextOutputFormatter());
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

However, that should actually be included by default, which is kind of strange. Still, in order to return a string, you need the `TextOutputFormatter`, so if returning a string is not working, then it must not be there. Perhaps you explicitly removed it?

Comment: TextOutputFormatter constructor is protected.  I tried options.OutputFormatters.Add(new StringOutputFormatter()); but still getting " Unsupported handler method return type 'System.String'.  It's a standard razor page project.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Pratt  Thanks for your help.  This seems to work

```
    public IActionResult OnGetTest()
    {
        return new ObjectResult("test");
    }
```